# Please explain the reason for this code not working

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

**The code given below should give different output on the basis of the input values but it is not working.**

```js
function myFunction() {
  let x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
  let y;
  if (x == "") {
    y = "The field is Empty";
  } else if (isNaN(x)) {
    y = "Input is not a number";
  } else if (x < 5) {
    y = "The number is too low";
  } else(x > 10) {
    y = "The number is too big";
  }
  document.getElementById("p01").innerHTML = y;
}
```

```html
<input id="demo" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Test Input</button>
<p id="p01"></p>
```

Comment: `} else(x > 10) {`, though if you require a number which is between 5 and 10, set a min/max and default on a number field and tell the user to enter a number between 5 and 10

Comment: I want the code to display the mentioned outputs in the p tag <p id="p01"></p> on the basis of the input given.

Comment: so when it's 6 you want it to display undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting a condition in the `else` statement: `else (x > 10)` which can't be done. Change it to `else if (x > 10)` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for helping. It is working the way I wanted.